# How can I resume my batch in another profile after reboot

Tags: batch-file, command-line, resume, reboot

I saw in many websites resume script after reboot in the same profile, but I really need resume my script after reboot in another profile, exactly in a new profile that I'm creating.

I couldn't find anything. I will be really grateful if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using %allusersprofile%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup